# How to write logs to a specific sink depending on the developement environment in Serilog?

Tags: c#, logging, configuration, azure-functions, serilog

I'm using Serilog with Azure Functions v4 and .NET 7. I am trying to write logs to both the local console and Application Insights. I already spent hours trying different solutions and the situation at the time of writing seems to be that this technology stack (Azure Functions + Application Insights) is not mature or too recent, and not yet very well documented.
Setting up `appsettings.{env}.json` files by environment and trying to add a different Serilog config by environment does not work with Azure Functions. Depending on the solution I tried, either Microsoft logger is used or there are no logs.
The code below is working for the console but I get duplicate logs on Application Insights. And if I remove Console sink, it works well in Application Insights but I get no more local logs:

```c#
.UseSerilog((hostBuilderContext, serviceProvider, loggerConfiguration) =>
    loggerConfiguration
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
            serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>(),
            TelemetryConverter.Traces)
)
```

I also tried other ways of setting up the logger, for example in `.ConfigureServices(...`, injecting it differently in the function code, but no luck. Many samples talk about a `Startup` method that I don't have. If it helps I can post the whole `Program.cs` and the function code here.
So I now added `.Enrich.WithEnvironmentName()` to get the environment name from an environment variable, and the **question** is: how can I filter the logs using `ByIncludingOnly` in the code above (not config file) to include logs depending on the environment name (`Local` or `Development`)? Same question for `ByExcluding` - I guess answer will be similar.

Comment: A complete cheesy but probably working way would be to tell the compiler to just compile the code if the environment is set to xxx with `#if Developement <code in new line> #else <code for other env> #endif`

Comment: @Hille Doesn't work for me unfortunately because as Azure Functions only recognizes 3 development names, I set mine to Local. And I want Development, Staging and Production to behave differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do it. I ended up not using the Environment enricher because it is at the time of writing not supporting the Azure environment variable for Azure Functions (`AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT`). See this issue:

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-enrichers-environment/issues/49

This is how I got this working:
*First option enriching the log event:*

```csharp
// Careful: Serilog is not able to enrich with the value of this variable and will default to 'Production'

var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Development";
var predicate = $"EnvironmentName = 'Local'";

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("EnvironmentName", value)
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()

    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(predicate)
        .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Properties} {Message}"))

    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .WriteTo.File(path: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\test.txt"))
    
    .CreateLogger();
```

*Second option without enriching the log event:*

```csharp
var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Development";
var predicate = $"{value} = 'Local'";

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()

    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(predicate)
        .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Properties} {Message}"))

    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .WriteTo.File(path: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\test.txt"))
    
    .CreateLogger();
```